# Difference between using match({property}) and WHERE clause in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've noticed that `match(a:Vegetable{name:'Cellery'}) return a` and `match(a:Vegetable) where a.name='Cellery' return a` gives me the same result.

Are there any practical differences between the two? The first form seems to work well when you know the property value, but is there a way to use wildcards or a LIKE condition with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE` options](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) show the execution plan of the query.

They show the exact same execution plan for both queries (on an empty database).

[image]

[image]

So performance-wise, the two notations should be completely the same.

> The first form seems to work well when you know the property value, but is there a way to use wildcards or a LIKE condition with it?

That's correct, `WHERE` gives you a lot more flexibility. Basically, the `MATCH` clause only allows you to check for equalities that could be written as `WHERE a.prop1 = value1  AND a.prop2 = value2 AND ...`. Meanwhile, `WHERE` allows you a lot more: the `AND`/`OR`/`XOR` and `NOT` logical operators, checking for inequalities; using `STARTS WITH`, `CONTAINS`, `ENDS WITH` and regular expressions; checking for node types like `WHERE (a:SomeLabel)` or even checking if the variables of the match are part of a pattern like `WHERE NOT (a)-[:SOME_REL]->(:SomeLabel)`.